# Quartz Composer Import and Display An Image Every x seconds?

Tags: quartz-composer

I want to call the `Image Importer` patch every x seconds and updated the `Sprite` patch with a new image accordingly. I'm new to Quartz Composer and not sure exactly how one can implement this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

But is the image itself, I mean the source changing ? Because the image importer patch will auto update.

You can

- Output the image importer to the value input of a sample & hold patch
- Bind a signal patch (hidden patch) to the "sampling" input of the sample & hold patch
- Set the signal patch to sample every x seconds.